# this.add1 is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, this

Why can't we bind this like here

```js
function UserCreator(name, score) {
  this.name = name;
  this.score = score;
}

UserCreator.prototype.increment = function () {
  function add1() {
    this.score++;
  }

  this.add1()
};

UserCreator.prototype.login = function () {
  console.log("login");
};

const user1 = new UserCreator("Eva", 9)
user1.increment()
```

returns "this.add1 is not a function". Of course, I can do it directly, but sometimes you need sub methods and I want to understand how this works

Comment: Can you please share what are you trying to achieve? :)

Comment: Your code is also a mess. You need to intend it properly and it would be a lot easier to understand. It would also help if you provided a live demo. The Stackoverflow question editor has a button for making live demos, which includes a feature to automatically fix your indentation. Use it.

Comment: Why do you decalre a function in a function which will be directly called? Just add `this.score++;` in the `UserCreator.prototype.increment` function withou an other function.

Comment: if that code were in strict mode, the error would be `this is undefined` ... along those lines anyway

Comment: when you call `add1` the value of `this` is not `user1` - there's a question about how `this` works on stackoverflow - someone should find it and dupe this

Comment: @Bravo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work I can't vote for a dupe, but this is the dupe I believe you are referencing.

Comment: Check out the methods Functions provide. In particular [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: @Daedalus - that's the one

Comment: So I think what's happening is that due to this being referring to windows. Code is running Windows.add1() and if just directly call add1() program should run Windows.score++ which is NaN

Comment: @user1076808 [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window), not Windows.  But to fix it simply replace `function add1()` with a proper prototype method like you have the others.  I can't say specifically why this is, from multiple reasons stretching from "it's late" to "I'm tired", but that should fix it, roughly.  I'm not going to add this as an answer.  Someone more knowledgeable can do that.

Answer (score 0):

So essentially its running `window.add1()` and if called using add1() it would run `window.score++` returning a NaN. Need to work on my "this" concepts.

Comment: At the point that you are calling `this.add1()`, `this` !== `window`. I suggest you use `console.log()` and/or the debugger in order to explore what is going on.